# Default JBoss 7 Connection Pool timeout

Tags: java, jboss, datasource, connection-pooling

Does anyone know what is the default connection timeout for in JBoss 7 when using connection pooling?

My datasource is defined like this

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<datasources>
   <xa-datasource jndi-name="java:/xxxxx" pool-name="xxxxx"
                  enabled="true" use-java-context="false">
      <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
      <xa-datasource-property name="URL">
         jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxxxxxx:1521:xxxxxxxx
      </xa-datasource-property>
      <driver>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver>
      <new-connection-sql>select 1 from dual</new-connection-sql>
      <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
      <xa-pool>
         <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
         <max-pool-size>50</max-pool-size>
         <is-same-rm-override>false</is-same-rm-override>
         <interleaving>false</interleaving>
         <pad-xid>false</pad-xid>
         <wrap-xa-resource>false</wrap-xa-resource>
      </xa-pool>
      <security>
         <user-name>
            xxxxxxxx
         </user-name>
         <password>xxxxxxx</password>
      </security>
      <validation>
         <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
         <background-validation>false</background-validation>
      </validation>
      <statement>
         <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
      </statement>
   </xa-datasource>
</datasources>
```

PS: I query my database and see the connections from my JBoss and cant figure out how it creates a new connection or when it uses an existing one from the pool. Mostly i have a couple of connections with status INACTIVE when the JBoss server is not used by any application.

Comment: Try to explore it via JMX web console